# Wcf Services in Ektron

Tags: ektron

I am working with WCF Services in Ektron(rrot/Workarea/Services).
When i am trying to consume the ContentService.svc service in a client using the following code,

```
   ContentManagerClient cClient = new ContentManagerClient();
   UpdatedContentService.ContentData data = new UpdatedContentService.ContentData();
   data.m_strTitle = "test";
   data.m_strHtml = "test";
   data.m_intFolderId = 72;
   data.m_intUserId = 1;
   cClient.Add(data);
```

I am getting the following error ' The current user does not have permission to carry out this request'.
How can i authenticate an ektron user to perform this action from a client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you received on the ektron dev forums was a good one. (prior discussion for anyone with the same problem: http://developer.ektron.com/forums/?v=t&t=1280)

You will need to use the Auth service, not the content service. this can be done using the following steps:

1. Create a proxy object for the web service:
   Run .Net tool wsdl.exe against your webservice address, e.g.   `http://localhost:/Workarea/webservices/AuthService.asmx`
2. Compile into DLL by running “csc /t:library AuthenticationService.cs”:
   Add the DLL as a reference to your DLL or console app
   Copy the DLL to a Lib folder in your project
3. Add the DLL as a reference to your DLL or console app
   Copy the DLL to a Lib folder in your project
   Right click “Add reference” and browse to your created proxy DLL.
   Add System.Web.Services as a reference to your DLL or console app
4. Call the proxy code from your app:

   AuthenticationService auth = new AuthenticationService();
   IAsyncResult response = auth.BeginisValidUser(username, password, etc...);

a working code example of this can be found at:
http://developer.ektron.com/Templates/CodeLibraryDetail.aspx?id=1036&blogid=116

This example was adapted from the VooDoo engineering example of pulling in the content service:
http://ektroneering.blogspot.com/2011/01/accessing-ektron-from-dll-or-console.html